# How to understand the flow of a JSF application from the code side?

Tags: jsf

I am trying to get into a big JSF application made by others with almost no documentation. I already got a general comprehension of the application architecture, and about what it should do from a functional point of view. But now I would like to understand what is the process in the code when I navigate in the application using my web browser.

I especially lack sequence diagrams that would show for a single story what code is called.

I tried using debug mode in eclipse and use break points to see what is called, but since a lot of code is called by the faces servlet, the step by step keeps returning into the JSF library and I am wasting a lot of time guessing what part of the code might be called next. I also look into the xhtml code to see what methods are called, but since each JSF page visible in the browser is made of a dozen of tiny xhtml fragments (using ui composition and custom components) it is quite easy to get lost.

So here is my question: Is there an easy way to associate a story from the browser point of view with the corresponding code in the backing beans?

Comment: Just read JSF specification document.

Comment: This is not my first JSF experience. But in the past I did not have to RE the app to understand what they did. Additionally they did not follow all JSF best practices. What I am asking here is not about how JSF work, but how to understand the internals of an application based on JSF

Comment: Basically and in short words, JSF is similarly to Struts or some other frameworks,  based in actions. You must follow this action flow to follow current view changes and view to view navigation. Take care about differing this actions and `get/set` methods, which are supposed to be property accessors. Having said that, your question is basically too broad to be answered here. A JSF book would do the trick.

Comment: Never thought I would got so much RTFM answers so fast in both my questions. Ok I will try to take a look at a book. Maybe a better understanding of JSF will help me understand what does the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok

I finally managed to get a better understanding of what was happening, thanks to all the comments on my questions, and to the facesTrace project, which was originally part of primefaces and aims to enhance the traceability of JavaServer Faces based applications. I found [here](http://thewonggei.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/how-to-setup-facestrace/) how to configure it, and I adapted it a little to my project. Suprinsingly, it worked very well (the project is JSF 1.1). Then I wanted to get the logs working in FacesTrace. I found a hint [there](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2006/04/20/facestrace_beta_is_out/), but had to adapt a little because the package name of the Appender has changed.

I would have loved to give a few more links but Stackoverflow limits me to two links, hope those will stay alive forever.

To be fair, using a good old logger and a context listener would produce the same result, but what I appreciate is that it is well presented and I can reduce the scope of the log to the log of the request, even though I have some doubts of what would happens if several users were debugging at the same time since it uses log4J.